# Are stably equivalent quadratic forms over Z equivalent?

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, integral-quadratic-forms

Let $Q_1, Q_2, R$ be quadratic froms over $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $Q_1 \oplus R \cong Q_2 \oplus R$ as quadratic forms. Is it necessary that $Q_1 \cong Q_2$?

I know that by Witt's theorem it is true for fields.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would say no; an example is when $R$ is a hyperbolic plane, the relation you demand says merely that $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ are in the same genus. This is in SPLAG, page 378 in the first (1988) edition, see also [Clark Jagy](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/Clark_Jagy_11_13_2013.pdf).

Notice that rational equivalence "without essential denominator" is exactly how Siegel defined the genus. So, $x^2 + 14 y^2$ and $2 x^2 + 7 y^2$ are rationally equivalent, and we can arrange that the denominators are prime to $14,$ but **not integrally equivalent**.

Give me a few minutes, I am going to display integer equivalence for $Q_1 = x^2 + 14 y^2,$ $Q_2 = 2 x^2 + 7 y^2,$ which pair take up a good deal of room in Cox's book, and $R = 2 z w.$ By solving $P^T A_1P = A_2$ in 4 by 4 integer matrices...

$$
A_1 =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
      1   &   0   &  0   &   0 \\
      0   &   14   &  0  &    0 \\
     0   &  0   &   0  &   1 \\
      0   &  0   &  1 &     0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
P =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
      2   &   7   &  -2   &   2 \\
      1   &   5   &  -2  &    1 \\
     -4   & -14   &   6  &   -3 \\
      2   &  14   &  -5 &     3
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
A_2 =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
      2   &   0   &  0   &   0 \\
      0   &   7   &  0  &    0 \\
     0   &  0   &   0  &   1 \\
      0   &  0   &  1 &     0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
\small
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
      2   &   1   &  -4   &   2 \\
      7   &   5   &  -14  &    14 \\
     -2   & -2   &   6  &   -5 \\
      2   &  1   &  -3 &     3
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
      1   &   0   &  0   &   0 \\
      0   &   14   &  0  &    0 \\
     0   &  0   &   0  &   1 \\
      0   &  0   &  1 &     0
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
      2   &   7   &  -2   &   2 \\
      1   &   5   &  -2  &    1 \\
     -4   & -14   &   6  &   -3 \\
      2   &  14   &  -5 &     3
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
      2   &   0   &  0   &   0 \\
      0   &   7   &  0  &    0 \\
     0   &  0   &   0  &   1 \\
      0   &  0   &  1 &     0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

check with gp-pari

=====================

```
parisize = 4000000, primelimit = 500509
? a1 = [ 1,0,0,0; 0,14,0,0; 0,0,0,1; 0,0,1,0]
%1 = 
[1 0 0 0]

[0 14 0 0]

[0 0 0 1]

[0 0 1 0]

? a2 = [ 2,0,0,0; 0,7,0,0; 0,0,0,1; 0,0,1,0]
%2 = 
[2 0 0 0]

[0 7 0 0]

[0 0 0 1]

[0 0 1 0]

? p = [ 2,7,-2,2; 1,5,-2,1; -4,-14,6,-3; 2,14,-5,3]
%3 = 
[2 7 -2 2]

[1 5 -2 1]

[-4 -14 6 -3]

[2 14 -5 3]

? matdet(p)
%4 = 1
? pt = mattranspose(p)
%5 = 
[2 1 -4 2]

[7 5 -14 14]

[-2 -2 6 -5]

[2 1 -3 3]

? a1
%6 = 
[1 0 0 0]

[0 14 0 0]

[0 0 0 1]

[0 0 1 0]

? pt * a1 * p
%7 = 
[2 0 0 0]

[0 7 0 0]

[0 0 0 1]

[0 0 1 0]

? a2
%8 = 
[2 0 0 0]

[0 7 0 0]

[0 0 0 1]

[0 0 1 0]

? pt * a1 * p - a2
%9 = 
[0 0 0 0]

[0 0 0 0]

[0 0 0 0]

[0 0 0 0]

?
```

===================